# Solve $x = \sin(y') + \ln(y')$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $x = \sin(y') + \ln(y')$

I made the substitution $y' = p$ to get $x = \sin(p) + \ln(p)$. Now differentiating with respect to $x$:

$$1 = \cos(p) \frac{dp}{dx} + \frac{1}{p} \frac{dp}{dx}$$
$$1 = \frac{dp}{dx} (\cos(p) + \frac{1}{p}) $$
$$ \frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{p}{p\cos(p) + 1}$$
$$\int \frac{p\cos(p) + 1}{p} dp =  \int dx \rightarrow x+C=\int \cos(p) + \frac{1}{p}dp$$
$$x+C=\sin(p) + \ln(p) \rightarrow x+C = x \rightarrow C = 0 ?$$

What does this mean ? The solution is $y= 0$?

Comment: You just took the derivative of a formula and integrated it and found that you “happened” to get the same formula. I don’t think there is a nice solution here.

Comment: Ok Apperently the solution is $x = \sin(p) + \ln(p)$ and $y = p\sin(p) + \cos(p) + p + C$. what does this mean to have a solution of this form? How do you get it?

Comment: How is that a solution, if the question is to solve the differential equation?

Comment: Oh, that’s a neat parametric solution. You already have x in terms of p, so you need to get y in terms of p. You can use that $p=y’=dy/dx=dy/dp/(dx/dp)$ - substitute each of those terms, get it terms of p and y and integrate.

Comment: Eric do you want to write the solution out so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s assume it’s possible to parametrize $x$ and $y$ in terms of $p$ so that $p=y’$.

As you’ve noticed, you can parametrize $x$ as $x=\sin(p)+\ln(p)$.

We now need to express $y$ in terms of $p$

We have $$p=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$p=\frac{\frac{dy}{dp}}{\frac{dx}{dp} }$$
$$p(\cos(p)+1/p)= \frac{dy}{dp}$$

Integrating gives $p\sin(p) +\cos(p) +p+c=y$.

This gives the desired parametrization which you can double check by calculating $dy/dx$.